Why doesn't the Gekko solver adapt to variations in the system?
The following is related to this question : predictive control model using GEKKO
I am still traying applying MPC to maintain the temperature of a room within a defined range(16,18), as Professor @John explained last time.the gain is normally listed as K=array([[0.93705481,−12.24012156]]). Thus, an increase in β by +1 leads to a decrease in T by -12.24, while an increase in Text by +1 leads to an increase in T by +0.937.
In my case, I tried to implement an external temperature profile for a day (sinusoidal), and I modified the control to vary between 0 and 1, not just 0 or 1, since the equipment can operate within this range. I also adjusted m.bint.MV_STEP_HOR=1 so that the control is updated at each iteration. However, the control still does not react! Even when the external temperature increases or decreases, the control remains unchanged.
I run the corrected code from my previous question:
# Import library
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import time
from gekko import GEKKO
from numpy import array

total_minutes_in_day = 24 * 60
interval = 5  # minutes
num_points = total_minutes_in_day // interval

# Générer les points de temps
time_points = np.linspace(0, total_minutes_in_day, num_points)

temperature = 8.5 + 11.5 * np.sin((2 * np.pi / total_minutes_in_day) * time_points - (np.pi / 2))
temperature = np.clip(temperature, -3, 20)


plt.plot(time_points, temperature)
plt.xlabel('Temps (minutes)')
plt.ylabel('Température (°C)')
plt.title('Variation de Tex sur une journée')
plt.savefig('Tex pour une jrn')
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()


K = array([[  0.93705481, -12.24012156]])
p =  {'a': array([[ 1.08945247],
        [-0.00242145],
        [-0.00245978],
        [-0.00272713],
        [-0.00295845],
        [-0.00319119],
        [-0.00343511],
        [-0.00366243],
        [-0.00394247],
        [-0.06665054]]),
 'b': array([[[-0.05160235, -0.01039767],
         [ 0.00173511, -0.01552485],
         [ 0.00174602, -0.01179519],
         [ 0.00180031, -0.01052658],
         [ 0.00186416, -0.00822121],
         [ 0.00193947, -0.00570905],
         [ 0.00202877, -0.00344507],
         [ 0.00211395, -0.00146947],
         [ 0.00223514,  0.00021945],
         [ 0.03800987,  0.04243736]]]),
 'c': array([0.0265903])}

# i have used only 200 mes of T_externel
T_externel = temperature
m = GEKKO(remote=False)
m.y = m.Array(m.CV,1)
m.u = m.Array(m.MV,2)
m.arx(p,m.y,m.u)

# rename CVs
m.T = m.y[0]

# rename MVs
m.beta = m.u[1]
m.free(m.beta)
m.bint = m.MV(0,lb=0,ub=1)
m.Equation(m.beta==m.bint)


# distrubance
m.d = m.u[0]

# distrubance and parametres
m.d = m.Param(T_externel[0])

m.bias = m.Param(0)
m.Tb = m.CV()
m.Equation(m.Tb==m.T+m.bias)

# steady state initialization
m.options.IMODE = 1
m.solve(disp=False)

# set up MPC
m.d.value = T_externel

m.options.IMODE   = 6 # MPC
m.options.CV_TYPE = 1 # the objective is an l1-norm (region)
m.options.NODES   = 2 # Collocation nodes
m.options.SOLVER  = 3 # IPOPT
m.time = np.arange(0,len(T_externel)*300,300) # step time = 300s

# Manipulated variables
m.bint.STATUS = 1  # calculated by the optimizer
m.bint.FSTATUS = 0 # use measured value
m.bint.DCOST = 0.0 # Delta cost penalty for MV movement
m.bint.UPPER = 1.0 # Upper bound
m.bint.LOWER = 0.0 # Lower bound
m.bint.MV_STEP_HOR = 1
m.bint.value = 0

# Controlled variables
m.Tb.STATUS = 1        # drive to set point
m.Tb.FSTATUS = 0       # receive measurement
m.Tb.SPHI = 18         # set point high level
m.Tb.SPLO = 16         # set point low level
m.Tb.WSPHI = 100       # set point high priority
m.Tb.WSPLO = 100       # set point low priority

T_MEAS = 20 # Temperature starts at 17
m.Tb.value = T_MEAS
m.bias.value = T_MEAS - m.T.value[0]

m.options.SOLVER = 1
m.solve(disp=False)

if m.options.APPSTATUS == 1:
   # Retrieve new values
   beta  = m.beta.NEWVAL
else:
   # Solution failed
   beta  = 0.0



@ John, , I tried varying m.bint.DCOST as well as m.Tb.WSPHI (high priority set point) and m.Tb.WSPLO (low priority set point), but it did not yield satisfactory results. Do you have any suggestions for improving these results? Thanks in advance, sir.

The solution that you showed was able to find a solution with a single step to keep within the temperature range (17-19). Tightening the temperature range (16.5-17.5) shows additional movement of the MV over the time period and shows that it is responsive. Unless there is a violation of this temperature range, the controller does not take action if there is even a small DCOST value to move the MV.

The dynamics influence the speed of the response. A better insulated building will have a slower response to changes in the external temperature. One other suggestion is that the bint Manipulated Variable isn't needed when solving for continuous instead of integer solutions.
Here is the complete code with bint removed and the tighter temperature target range:
# Import library
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import time
from gekko import GEKKO
from numpy import array
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

total_minutes_in_day = 24 * 60
interval = 5  # minutes
num_points = total_minutes_in_day // interval

# Générer les points de temps
time_points = np.linspace(0, total_minutes_in_day, num_points)

temperature = 8.5 + 11.5 * np.sin((2 * np.pi / total_minutes_in_day) * time_points - (np.pi / 2))
temperature = np.clip(temperature, -3, 20)

K = array([[  0.93705481, -12.24012156]])
p =  {'a': array([[ 1.08945247],
        [-0.00242145],
        [-0.00245978],
        [-0.00272713],
        [-0.00295845],
        [-0.00319119],
        [-0.00343511],
        [-0.00366243],
        [-0.00394247],
        [-0.06665054]]),
 'b': array([[[-0.05160235, -0.01039767],
         [ 0.00173511, -0.01552485],
         [ 0.00174602, -0.01179519],
         [ 0.00180031, -0.01052658],
         [ 0.00186416, -0.00822121],
         [ 0.00193947, -0.00570905],
         [ 0.00202877, -0.00344507],
         [ 0.00211395, -0.00146947],
         [ 0.00223514,  0.00021945],
         [ 0.03800987,  0.04243736]]]),
 'c': array([0.0265903])}

T_externel = temperature
m = GEKKO(remote=False)
m.y = m.Array(m.CV,1)
m.u = m.Array(m.MV,2)
m.arx(p,m.y,m.u)

# rename CVs
m.T = m.y[0]

# rename MVs
m.beta = m.u[1]

# distrubance
m.d = m.u[0]

# distrubance and parametres
m.d = m.Param(T_externel[0])

m.bias = m.Param(0)
m.Tb = m.CV()
m.Equation(m.Tb==m.T+m.bias)

# steady state initialization
m.options.IMODE = 1
m.solve(disp=False)

# set up MPC
m.d.value = T_externel

m.options.IMODE   = 6 # MPC
m.options.CV_TYPE = 1 # the objective is an l1-norm (region)
m.options.NODES   = 2 # Collocation nodes
m.options.SOLVER  = 3 # IPOPT
m.time = np.arange(0,len(T_externel)*300,300) # step time = 300s

# Manipulated variables
m.beta.STATUS = 1  # calculated by the optimizer
m.beta.FSTATUS = 0 # use measured value
m.beta.DCOST = 0.0 # Delta cost penalty for MV movement
m.beta.UPPER = 1.0 # Upper bound
m.beta.LOWER = 0.0 # Lower bound
m.beta.MV_STEP_HOR = 1
m.beta.value = 0

# Controlled variables
m.Tb.STATUS = 1        # drive to set point
m.Tb.FSTATUS = 0       # receive measurement
m.Tb.SPHI = 17.5         # set point high level
m.Tb.SPLO = 16.5         # set point low level
m.Tb.WSPHI = 100       # set point high priority
m.Tb.WSPLO = 100       # set point low priority

T_MEAS = 20
m.Tb.value = T_MEAS
m.bias.value = T_MEAS - m.T.value[0]

m.options.SOLVER = 3
m.solve(disp=False)

if m.options.APPSTATUS == 1:
   # Retrieve new values
   beta  = m.beta.NEWVAL
else:
   # Solution failed
   beta  = 0.0

# Plot the results
plt.figure(figsize=(8,3.5))
plt.subplot(2,1,1)
plt.plot(m.time,m.Tb.value,'r-',label=r'$T_{biased}$')
plt.plot(m.time,m.T.value,'r--',label=r'$T_{unbiased}$')
plt.plot(m.time,m.d.value,'g:',label=r'$T_{ext}$')
plt.plot([0,m.time[-1]],[m.Tb.SPHI,m.Tb.SPHI],'k--',label='Upper Bound')
plt.plot([0,m.time[-1]],[m.Tb.SPLO,m.Tb.SPLO],'k--',label='Lower Bound')
plt.ylabel('Temperature (°C)')
plt.legend(loc=1); plt.grid()
plt.subplot(2,1,2)
plt.step(m.time,m.beta.value,'b--',label=r'$\beta$')
plt.ylabel('optimal control')
plt.xlabel('Time (sec)')
plt.legend(loc=1); plt.grid()
plt.savefig('results.png',dpi=300)
plt.show()


@ John Thank you again, professor, for these clarifications. However, what I still don't understand is why, sometimes, when the outside temperature rises, the inside temperature remains constant. Normally, it should also increase since beta remains constant. there ara some exemples for this (https://i.sstatic.net/f5iEmZK6.png) (https://i.sstatic.net/6GhOpaBM.png)

In the two images, we can see that on the second day, the outside temperature increases and β remains constant, but the inside temperature decreases.

It looks like it is a dynamics issue. The response to beta (and likely external temperature) is very slow as shown in the step response here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78818420/2366941  This could be from using a different sampling time interval for the SysID (System Identification) and the controller. This is especially the case if you used a short time interval for system identification and use a longer time interval for the MPC application. Because it is a discrete ARX model, the dynamics will take longer for the inputs to affect the outputs.

Could you include a new question with the 2 day plots and the sample code used to generate them? Also, please include details about the sampling interval for the system identification data and the MPC.
